# observing related model properties in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models that are related to each other, a `RequestMatcher` and `Response`. A `RequestMatcher` has many `Responses` but only one`activeResponse`. How do i observe the `activeResponse` on the `RequestMatcher` model so i can use that in templates? Here's what i have.

```
// request-matcher.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    path: DS.attr('string'),
    project: DS.belongsTo('project', {async: true}),
    responses: DS.hasMany('response', {inverse: 'requestMatcher', async: true}),
    activeResponse: DS.attr('number'),
    matches_get_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_post_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_put_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_delete_request: DS.attr()
});
```

and

```
//response.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    status_code: DS.attr('number'),
    requestMatcher: DS.belongsTo('requestMatcher', {async: true}),
    isActiveResponse: function() {

        if (this.get('isNew')) {
            return false;
        }

        var id = parseInt(this.get('id'));

        return this.get('requestMatcher').then(function (requestMatcher) {

            if (!requestMatcher) {
                return false;
            }

            var activeResponseId = requestMatcher.get('activeResponse');

            return activeResponseId === id;
        });
    }.property('requestMatcher.activeResponse')
});
```

I'm using a number as `activeResponse` because ember has trouble referencing the same model type twice on the same model. I can't get the .property() to work correctly on my `Response` model. It always renders as `true`. I've also tried this approach but the observer never gets triggered.

```
//request-matcher.js 
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    path: DS.attr('string'),
    project: DS.belongsTo('project', {async: true}),
    responses: DS.hasMany('response', {inverse: 'requestMatcher', async: true}),
    activeResponse: DS.attr('number'),
    matches_get_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_post_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_put_request: DS.attr(),
    matches_delete_request: DS.attr(), 
    onActiveResponseChange: function() {
        Ember.run.once(this, 'setActiveResponse');
    }.observes('activeResponse', 'isLoaded'),

    setActiveResponse: function() {

        var activeResponseId = parseInt(this.get('activeResponse'));

        this.get('responses').then(function (responses) {
            responses.forEach(function (response) {
                var isActive = activeResponseId === parseInt(response.get('id'));
                response.set('isActiveResponse', isActive);
            });
        });   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a number as activeResponse because ember has trouble referencing the same model type twice on the same model.

Therein lies your problem. That should definitely be a relationship and not a number. I've achieved something *very* similar to this in Ember-Data before, so unless they've made breaking changes in the new betas, you should be able to accomplish it. Here is how I personally would declare those relationships:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    responses: DS.hasMany('response', { inverse: 'requestMatcher', async: true }),
    activeResponse: DS.belongsTo('response', { inverse: null, async: true })
});
```

Setting the `inverse` to `null` will ensure that your `Response` class doesn't have to know about the relationship (it doesn't seem like it needs to anyway). Now you can use Ember-Data like you would with any other relationship, only you don't have to change anything in the `Response` model. This should allow you to observe your `activeResponse` properties as you normally would.